# ASP.NET Browser Cache causing issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser-cache

I have looked for answers to this question, but I am not sure if I am asking it right.

I am looking for what do developers do in this situation:

I am developing an ASP.NET C# applications.  I have CSS and SCRIPT files, and I am using jQuery.  I install my application to the Web Servers (or I have my customer install them).  If I have made any changes to my script files by adding some new jQuery or something, my customers don't get that effect after I do an update.  I assume that the reason is that their browsers cache the file on the local computer and they do now download the new file from the server.

In my development environment I clear the cache when I close the browser and on IE I tell it in options to always load from the server.  That way when developing I never have cached data.

What is the best practice to make sure that if I do make changes, those files get refreshed on the client computers after I do an update?  Is there something in Code I can do?

I really don't want to change the filename and update all my script references.

Thanks,
Cory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way is to append a query string argument to the end of the reference to the css/script file path. For example, if you append a build number as the query string, each version of the software will make its own request for the relevant resource.

Comment: Oh... I have been adding a random number at the end of each Page URL.  So your saying at the end of the URL for the resource?

Comment: Yes - when the page loads it will make separate requests for script and css files hooked up using `link`. If you append your random number to that you should be good.

Comment: the problem about random number or date is it never caches the script/css files. If you add a version number to end of the reference url (eg /script/myscript.js?v=2) the browser will cache the file as long as the v equals 2.

Comment: Awesome!  I just add a new Guid at the end of is resource... that way I force the issue to download that file each time.  I will have to look to see if it takes too much resources to do so.

Comment: I would recommend following `Onur TOPAL`'s suggestion of a simple `v=2` suffix to keep it simple